# Can't create fb_app with name containing the word "connect"

Tags: facebook-apps

I'm developing this e-commerce:
http://boconnect.com.br

And I'd like to add a share button in the wishlist section. Therefore, I tried to create a fb app to be able to use the jssdk.
But then I found out that I can't create an app with the e-commerce name "BoCONNECT", because it contains the word 'connect'.

Is there a way around?